# How to close Seaborn plots

Tags: python, seaborn

I am running a loop to extract data and graph plots using Seaborn, Pandas and Python.  I just want to save each plot as a graphic and close it but I am not able to figure out how to do this.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py:311: RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control this warning, see the rcParam `figure.max_open_warning`).

I had expected g.close() to work but I got the error:
AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'close'

```
    for o in options:
        s = "SELECT * from options_yahoo where contract_name = '" + o + "'
        SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query(s, conn)
        df = pd.DataFrame(SQL_Query)
        g = sns.relplot( kind="line", data=df[['bid','ask','lastprice']])
        g.savefig( o+ ".png")
        g.close()
```

I expect to be able to have a more efficient solution that doesn't use up so much memory and bring warning errors.  Some best practices would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to access the figure itself to close: `g.fig.close()`

Comment: @busybear `g.fig.close()` results in an `AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'close'`. Use `plt.close(g.fig)` instead, see my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

Seaborn plots responds to pyplot commands, you can do `plt.close()` to close the current figure, even if it was plotted by Seaborn

Comment: Notice it is `plt.close()` (matplotlib.pyplot) not `sns.close()` or `sns_plot.close()` (seaborn)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to close a specific figure corresponding to a seaborn plot (e.g. a FacetGrid) called `sns_plot`, use:

```
plt.close(sns_plot.fig)
```

Comment: I did as below.

```python
plt.close(g.fig)
```